# Screen Sharing and video/audio calling using WebRTC and Electron on Mac OS

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, webrtc, getusermedia

I am trying to create an electron application which can share the desktop with the system audio using webrtc and if I set the constraints :

```
const constraints = {
 audio: {
 mandatory: {
  chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
 }
  },
video: {
mandatory: {
 chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
}
 }
  }
```

I got this issue **Mac OS audio**:

**ERROR:adm_helpers.cc(73)] Failed to query stereo recording.** and then " **NotFoundError: Requested device not found** "

Answer (score 1):

You need to use electron's `desktopCapturer` api.

Example -

```
// In the renderer process.
const {desktopCapturer} = require('electron')

desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window', 'screen']}, (error, sources) => {
  if (error) throw error
  for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; ++i) {
    if (sources[i].name === 'Electron') {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            chromeMediaSourceId: sources[i].id,
            minWidth: 1280,
            maxWidth: 1280,
            minHeight: 720,
            maxHeight: 720
          }
        }
      })
      .then((stream) => handleStream(stream))
      .catch((e) => handleError(e))
      return
    }
  }
})

function handleStream (stream) {
  const video = document.querySelector('video')
  video.srcObject = stream
  video.onloadedmetadata = (e) => video.play()
}

function handleError (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

And use the `audio` flag above for getting the audio while screen sharing.

More details here - https://electronjs.org/docs/api/desktop-capturer

Comment: Yes, I do but the point is if you set audio to 'true' it will not work on MacOS. Did you try to enable audio on mac os?

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS users you need to get audio and video streams separately, then merge the streams like so:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: {
        mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            chromeMediaSourceId: source.id
        }
    }
});
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
        mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop'
        }
    },
    video: false
}).then(function(audioStream) {
  var audioTracks = audioStream.getAudioTracks();

  // merge audio and video tracks
  if(audioTracks.length > 0) {
    stream.addTrack(audioTracks[0]);
  }

    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: 'YOUR MIME TYPE'
    });

    recorder.ondataavailable = yourDataHandler;
    recorder.onstop = yourStopHandler;

    recorder.start();
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.error('audioTrackError', err);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure this works on MacOS??